# Songs doesn't display instantly as soon as runtime permission is given

Tags: android, android-runtime

I'm a making a music app and I have created a function to load songs from the external storage. I have given the runtime permission for marshmallow but the problem is as soon as I grant the permission the songs are not displayed. But when i stop the app and reopen it, I can see the songs displayed. I want to display the songs as soon as I give the runtime permission (read from external storage). Thanks!

Songs.java fragment class:

```
public class Songs extends Fragment  {

private static final String TAG = "Songs";
RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<SongInfoModel> SongList = new ArrayList<SongInfoModel>();
SongAdapter songAdapter;

SongInfoModel s;

ScaleInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter;





  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
  container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_activity, container, false);


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


   LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new 
   LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

   songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(), SongList);
   alphaAdapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(songAdapter);
   alphaAdapter.setDuration(1000);
   alphaAdapter.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
   alphaAdapter.setFirstOnly(false);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(alphaAdapter);




   Collections.sort(SongList, new Comparator<SongInfoModel>(){
       public int compare(SongInfoModel a, SongInfoModel b){
           return a.getSongName().compareTo(b.getSongName());
       }
   });



loadSongs();


   return view;
}


public void loadSongs(){

    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+"!=0";
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri,null,selection,null,null);
    if(cursor != null){
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                     (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                      (MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));
                String url = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                      (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));
                long duration = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex
                                      (MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));
         s = new SongInfoModel(name,artist,null,null,url,duration,null);
                SongList.add(s);

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        songAdapter = new SongAdapter(getContext(),SongList);

    }

       private void checkUserPermission(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
          if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), 
      Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]
      {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},123);
            return;
        }
    }
    loadSongs();
}

  @Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] 
                     permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 123:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                loadSongs();
            }else
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission 
                                        Denied",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                checkUserPermission();
            }
            break;
            default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, 
                                                           grantResults);

       }

    }


  }
```

Comment: show your code what have you done

Comment: @Sebin Paul Once permission is granted , fetch it using media store and ContentResolver, I assume this is being done, make sure you are notifying the RecyclerView/ListView

Comment: I have posted the code, would you care to look into it and tell what's is wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited answer to the edited question**

In the `onCreateView` method, before return statement, you've called `loadSongs();` Instead of that, call `checkUserPermission();`

**Old answer**

You should also perform the post permission grant task inside the method `onRequestPermissionsResult` by overriding it in your activity.

You may use my helper library to get rid of it. https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: I have posted the code, would you care to look into it and tell what's is wrong :(

Comment: Already tried that! But thank you for your help. Problem solved!

Comment: Glad I could help. Did you check my library? ;)

Comment: Yes, its good. I'll be needing some more help with the app I'm building. Is there any way I could get in contact with you, if you don't mind?

Comment: You can share your problems here at Stack Overflow. Here are a lot of developers trying to help other developers.